# Responsive placeholder text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, placeholder

I need a `placeholder` which will contain dynamic value:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search by Name, Order Number and Location" style="width: 300px" />

<input type="text" placeholder="Search by Name" style="width: 300px" />
```

and I need to display all the placeholder text in the Input field. It is ok to reduce the font-size, but need to be in dynamic way.

Any idea?

Comment: I suggest you edit your post, I have read it 3 times and I still can't make much sense of it at all. So you want the input box to remain the same size no matter what text is in the placeholder? If so why not specify a width?

Comment: @Anthony'Runt'Cleaves he wants the placeholder text to always be visible regardless of input width.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var step = 0.1;

setInterval(function() {
  // Loop over input elements
  $('input').each(function() {
    // Only change font-size if input value is empty (font-size should only affect placeholder)
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
      // Create clone
      $clone = $('<span></span>')
        .appendTo('body')
        .addClass('inputClone')
        .text($(this).attr('placeholder'));
      // Adjust font-size of clone
      var fontSize = $(this).css('font-size');
      do {
        fontSize = parseFloat($clone.css('font-size')) - step;
        $clone.css({
          'font-size': fontSize
        });
      } while ($clone.width() > $(this).width());
      // Maintain input field size
      $(this).css({
        "width": $(this).width() + "px",
        "height": $(this).height() + "px"
      });
      // Change input font-size
      $(this).animate({
        'font-size': fontSize
      });
      // Delete clone
      $clone.remove();
    } else {
      // Default input field back to normal
      $(this)
        .finish()
        .clearQueue()
        .attr('style', function(i, style) {
          // Remove inline style for font-size
          return style.replace(/font-size[^;]+;?/g, '');
        });
    }
  });
}, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="name1" placeholder="Search by Name, Order Number and Location" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="name2" placeholder="Search by Name"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Create another field and append it

Comment: It is not displaying the Text completely.

Comment: @JaganC yes, but his approach is probably what you'd use. That is, 1) clone the text into another element. 2) Calculate its size. 3) Continually resize clone until it is small enough. 4) Use its `font-size` to update to input element. For the record, I don't think your original idea (resizing placeholder text) is sound. Maybe a better approach would be to avoid long placeholder values?

Comment: @romellem yeah I got, already implemented this solution, but client is not agreeing on this solution. He wants to display the long placeholder no matter what size it is.